# What am I doing wrong with $set and $inc in update

Tags: mongodb

I am trying this at the [mongodb console](http://www.mongodb.org/#):

```
db.foobar.update( 
  { name: "Foobar" },
  { 
    $set : { foo: { bar: 'bar' }, 
    $inc: { 'foo.count': 1 } 
  } 
}, true)
```

It returns with "ok", but `db.foobar.find()`, returns an empty record set. I'm trying to `upsert` a document, so it looks like the:

```
name: Foobar
foo: {
  bar: 'bar'
  count: 1
}
```

If the doc doesn't exist then create one with a count of 1. Otherwise, just increase the count. Why isn't above working?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

It seems to me that your code is actually trying to set the $inc field of the document rather than using the $inc modifier on the foo.count field.  This might be what you want:

```
db.foobar.update(
    { name: "Foobar" }, 
    {
        $set: { 'foo.bar': 'bar' }, 
        $inc: { 'foo.count': 1 } 
    }, true)
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: That works. But why doesn't this work: `db.foobar.update( { name: "Foobar" }, { $set: { foo: { bar: 'bar' } }, $inc: { 'foo.count': 1 } }, true)` It seems setting in a string will make it work. But I wonder why

Comment: I hadn't noticed that! The error message provided by the shell is 'have conflicting mods in update'. To me this suggests that $set operates on the 'foo' subdocument as a whole, hence you can't use $inc on 'foo' or any of its properties, such as 'foo.count'.  I conjecture that using $set on 'foo.bar' and $inc on 'foo.count' works because the two modifiers target disjoint parts of the document.

Answer (score 3):

In the code snippet youprovided, you're missing a closing curly bracket after the $set object. But that's a side issue.

I don't believe you can set and increment the same sub document in one transaction.
Since count is a member under foo, on an upsert, it won't exist yet.  The error I get when I try the following:

```
db.foobar.update( 
   { name: "Foobar" },
   { 
     $set : { foo: { bar: 'bar' }}, 
     $inc: { 'foo.count': 1 } 
   } 
}, true)
```

is "conflicting mods in update".
Maybe you can model it this way:

```
db.foobar.update({name:"foobar"},{$set:{foo:{bar:"bar"}},$inc:{count:1}},true);
```

or if you prefer:

```
db.foobar.update({name:"foobar"},{$set:{foo:{bar:"bar"}},$inc:{"counts.foo":1}},true);
```

Answer (score 0):

So I'm currently trying:

```
var doc = {
            "name": "thename",
            "organisation": "theorganisation"
        }, // document to update. Note: the doc here matches the existing array
    query = { "email": "email@example" }; // query document
    query["history.name"] = doc.name; // create the update query
    query["history.organisation"] = doc.organisation;
    var update = db.getCollection('users').findAndModify({
        "query": query,
        "update": { 
            "$set": { 
                "history.$.name": doc.name,
                "history.$.organisation": doc.organisation
            },
            "$inc": { "history.$.score": 5 } //increment score
        }
    });
    if (!update) {
        db.getCollection('users').update(
            { "email": query.email },
            { "$push": { "history": doc } }
        );
    }
    db.getCollection('users').find({ "email": "email@example" });
```

This updates the `score`, and adds it to the object if it doesn't exist, however it seems to change all the objects `name`s to doc.name (i.e "thename" in this case).

I haven't got onto if the doc doesn't exist yet